# Efficient way of Creating dummy variables in python

Tags: python

I want to create a vector of dummy variables(can take only O or 1). I am doing the following:

```
data = ['one','two','three','four','six']
variables = ['two','five','ten']
```

I got the following two ways:

```
dummy=[]
for variable in variables:
    if variable in data:
        dummy.append(1)
    else:
        dummy.append(0)
```

or with list comprehension:

```
dummy = [1 if variable in data else 0 for variable in variables]
```

Results are ok:

```
>>> [1,0,0]
```

Is there a build in function doing this task quicker? Its kinda slow if the variables are thousands.

**Edit**: Results using `time.time()`:
I am using the following data:

```
data = ['one','two','three','four','six']*100
variables = ['two','five','ten']*100000
```

- Loop(from my example): 2.11 sec
- list comprehension: 1.55 sec
- list comprehension (variables are type of set): 0.0004992 sec
- Example from Peter: 0.0004999 sec
- Example from falsetrue: 0.000502 sec

Comment: Using `set` will be faster, instead of `list`, i.e., `variables = set(['two','five','ten'])`

Comment: you might want to look at numpy arrays or pandas series or data frames if you are working with such amount of data

Comment: @SparkandShine: And if it's an actual literal, you can skip the intermediate `list` on Python 2.7+ and just use `variables =  {'two', 'five', 'ten'}` to get the `set` directly.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, thx for this update.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you convert `data` to a `set` the lookup will be quicker.

You can also convert the boolean to an integer to get `1` or `0` for `True` or `False`.

```
>>> int(True)
1
```

You can call `__contains__` on the set of data for each variable so save creating the set each time through the loop.

You can map all these together:

```
dummy = list(map(int, map(set(data).__contains__, variables)))
```

**edit:**

Much as I like one-liners, I think it's more readable to use a list comprehension.

If you create the `set` in the list comprehension it will recreate it for each `variable`. So we need two lines:

```
search = set(data)
dummy = [int(variable in search) for variable in variables]
```

Comment: Note: `True` and `False` are already `int`s with the value `1` and `0` respectively (`bool` is a subclass of `int` with two singleton instances, and different representations). You can use `True`/`False` in mathematical expressions just fine, so unless you need them represented as "real" `int`s when printed/stringified, you could omit the `int` conversion in favor of just `dummy = list(map(set(data).__contains__, variables))`. Good answer BTW, up-voted.

Comment: @ShadowRanger OP wanted `[1, 0, 0]`

Comment: I know, I was adding that only as a comment that logically, `[True, False, False]` can serve all the same purposes as `[1, 0, 0]` aside from string representation, so if they only need it for internal use, not for display, they could skip a step. I'm not saying your answer is wrong or incomplete (I like it a lot; it's exactly what I'd do in the same situation), just mentioning this as an elaboration for the OP's benefit.

Answer (score 2):

- Use `set` - `item in set` take O(1) / `item in list` take O(n)
- You can use int(bool) to get 1 or 0. (instead of conditional expression)

---

```
>>> data = ['one','two','three','four','six']
>>> variables = ['two','five','ten']
>>> xs = set(data)
>>> [int(x in xs) for x in variables]
[1, 0, 0]
```